# Combobox selected item always set to index 1 when BindingSource updated

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binding

I have a Binding source shared between two UserControls. One control is used to managed the source (adding items), and into the second control I associate one item of the source to an object property.

On 1st control I have a `ListBox` binded to a `BindingSource` based on a `BindingList` and a button to add new item. Working fine.

On the 2nd control I have a `Combobox` where items are binded to a `BindingSource` based on the same `BindingList` as 1st control.

I don't understand why, but when I add one item to the BindingSource throw the 1st control, the combobox selected item (on the 2nd control) becomes always the item corresponding to the index 1.
The expected behavior, is I want to save the combobox selection regarding its context among the listbox list. For future, I plan to use several combobox in the same control that may point on a different selection (but among the same base list).

On the 1st control :

```vb
    Private bs As BindingSource
    Private bl As BindingList(Of Variable)

    Public Overloads Sub Show(variables As BindingList(Of Variable))
        bl = variables
        bs = New BindingSource(bl, Nothing)

        'Bindings
        LbVariables.DisplayMember = "Identifiant"
        LbVariables.DataSource = bs

        Dim bd As New Binding("Visible", LbVariables, "SelectedIndex", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        AddHandler bd.Format, AddressOf LbVariables_Format
        PanelVariable.DataBindings.Add(bd)

    End Sub

    Private Sub LbVariables_Format(sender As Object, cevent As ConvertEventArgs)
        'LbVariables.SelectedIndex >= 0
        cevent.Value = cevent.Value >= 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtAdd.Click
        Dim v As New Variable("var" & i)
        bl.Add(v)
    End Sub
```

On the 2nd control :

```vb
    Private bs As BindingSource
    Private bl As BindingList(Of Variable)

    Public Sub SetData(v As ParaVariable, variables As BindingList(Of Variable))
        'in 1st
        CbVariable.DataBindings.Clear()

        bl = variables
        bs = New BindingSource(bl, Nothing)

        'Bindings
        CbVariable.DisplayMember = "Identifiant"
        CbVariable.ValueMember = "Identifiant"
        CbVariable.DataSource = bs      

        CbVariable.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", v, "IdVariable"))
    End Sub
```

`ParaVariable` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` on its `IdVariable` property (string). `Variable` has a property named `Identifiant` (string) which I'd like to save in `v.IdVariable` (regarding the combobox selected item).
On `Show(...)` and `SetData(...)` methods, the `variables` passed is the same object.

I've also tried to share a `BindingSource` instead of `BindingList(Of Variable)` but I have the same behavior.

Using .Net Framework 4.8 and WinForms.

**EDIT :**

I understood my mistake. On the combobox control I have some other bindings and particularly a binding between a checkbox `Visible` property and the combobox `SelectedIndex` (like binding between `LbVariables` and `PanelVariable`). I misunderstood the `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` and I didn't know there was also a `ControlUpdateMode` property. So when the checkbox visibility was changed, the selection of the combobox was set to `(int)bool => 0/1` :(

Changing to `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never` solve the issue.

Comment: What's this for: `CbVariable.DataBindings.Add(...)`? Is that meant to be a *one-way binding* of sort? -- Pass the initialized BindingSource directly

Comment: I use this binding to select the right item in the combobox. `v` stores the value of the selected item in the property `IdVariable`, so I use this binding to keep it synchronized, it should be two-way (I'd like to).

Comment: What is the *right item*? Your Controls are already bound to a source of data, which is supposed to be the same. Isn't the current item in the ListBox the *right item* to show in the ComboBox?

Comment: What I want is to have the same _list_ but not the same _selection_. I use the listbox to edit the list, but I use combobox to define a selection of this list regarding the combobox context. At the end, I may have several combobox in the same control pointing on a different selection (but with a identical base list). It is what I try to do

Comment: Now it's more clear. Remove the comment and add this information to the question (since it's quite vital) -- You also need to show what calls `SetData()` and with what, which also implies you need to describe what is `v`, what it's sets to, how `ParaVariable` relates to `Variable` and whether `ParaVariable` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`